# How do I filter from a column containing a list of time intervals in tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I'm sorry not to be able to provide a sample dataset for this problem, but I hope I'll be able to provide enough information for people to understand my question.

I have a large dataframe of tag detections from which I would like to remove all detections that lie within one or more given intervals. The relevant columns in my dataframe are `data$ts` (a vector of POSIXct values containing the time of each detection), `data$ID` (a vector with the ID's of each individual), and the more complex `data$remove` column, which contains a list of intervals (created using the lubridate package).

I would like to filter my database so that all observations that lie within at least one interval in the `data$remove` column are eliminated. This is what I tried:

```
data %>%
filter(sum(ts %within% remove) != 0)
```

and this is the error that I get:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `sum(ts %within% remove) != 0`.
x When second argument to %within% is a list it must contain interval objects only
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I guess this has something to do with the structure of my lists in `data$remove`. Interestingly, though, when running the code on single lines of the dataframe, as in

```
data$ts[[1]] %within% data$remove[[1]]
```

the code works just fine, giving me a list of TRUEs and FALSEs as output, which I can then easily `sum()`.

To try and help understand the structure of the `data$remove` column, I'm pasting the output that I get when I visualize the first line of my dataframe

```
data$remove[[1]]

###the following is the output
$to_be_removed
[1] 2019-04-09 07:00:00 UTC--2019-04-09 08:00:00 UTC
[2] 2019-04-10 05:30:00 UTC--2019-04-10 06:30:00 UTC
```

I hope this is understandable. I could not find any similar questions online and I'll be happy to provide more detail if someone points me to what further information would be necessary! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error message tells you the problem. Somewhere in your lists under `data$remove` there seem to be objects that are not intervals. You need to find those and either remove or correct them

Comment: Thanks Julian. How can I check for objects that are not intervals in that column? It would seem strange to me that there is anything else in those lists, since they were all created with the same procedure in one step. But I can definitely search for non-interval objects, would be great if you could point me to a method to do that (my dataframe has over 2 mln rows). Thanks!

Comment: `lubridate::is.interval` is the function you're looking for. Then you have to apply this to each element in the list via e.g. `sapply` or `lapply`